# SQL sum with limit

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, limit

i need to sum working hours from employees with some limitations. My code right now just for one employee:

```
SELECT rp.mnr,
       trunc(sum(rp.OUT_DATE-rp.IN_DATE)*24, 2) AS "Hours"
FROM table1 rp
WHERE rp.CALC_DATE >= '01.04.2022' and rp.CALC_DATE <= '30.4.2022'
AND rp.MNR = 90590
GROUP BY rp.MNR 
ORDER BY rp.mnr desc

MNR  |Hours |
-----+------+
90590|181.98|
```

I need to split this sum with hours limit 50.. Result should look like:

```
MNR  |Hours |
-----+------+
90590|50.00|
90590|50.00|
90590|50.00|
90590|31.98|
```

Anyone can help me with that ?

DB: Oracle.

Thank you!

MF

Comment: What database are you using? Solutions vary per database engine.

Comment: In this case it is Oracle..

Comment: What should be other columns for these identical rows with 50 hrs? You will not be able to distinguish them

Comment: i don't need to destinguish them .. i just need data in form like that, that i can use them in next operation..

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the required rows to get your desired output. CONNECT BY clause is one of the method -

```
WITH DATA AS (<YOUR SELECT QUERY GIVING COLUMNS AS MNR AND HOURS>),
FIXED_AMOUNT AS (SELECT 50 AMT FROM DUAL),
CALC AS (SELECT D.*, AMT, SUM(AMT) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) CUMM_SUM
           FROM DATA D, FIXED_AMOUNT
        CONNECT BY (LEVEL - 1) * 50 <= HOURS)
SELECT MNR, CASE WHEN HOURS_ - CUMM_SUM < 0
                      THEN HOURS_ - CUMM_SUM + AMT
                 ELSE AMT
            END HOURS
  FROM CALC;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d86b758e11b330bafa70fb013a23b302)

Comment: What about this case, when i have more employees in starting table:

https://dbfiddle.uk/FJpKXMjn

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZWlhBQt9